# Возможно в административной панели Django сделать пользовательские поля?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Собственно интересует вот такие вопросы:
Есть ли возможность задать конкретным полям определённую маску?
Возможно ли убрать из поля integer стрелки?
Возможно ли определить размер поля и длину вводимых данных, хотя если есть возможность создавать маску, то я думаю там это можно будет и сделать?!

Answer (score 2):

Да, внести изменения в стили панели администратора возможно, предлагаю вам посмотреть в сторону переопределения admin.py.

Если кратко, то вы создаете и наполняете .css файлы (в некоторых случаях .js) необходимыми вам изменениями и отображаете ссылки на эти файлы в admin.py, пример кода:

```
from django.contrib import admin
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    class Media:   
        css = {
             'all': ('/templates/css/admin-extra.css ',)
        }


admin.site.register(MyModel,MyModelAdmin)
```